# How to store XML text in variable

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to name the XML file I am writing based on the child's first subelement. However, with this code all I am returning is file_None.xml

I have tried

```
name = ET.SubElement(child, 'data').text
name = str(ET.SubElement(child, 'data').text)
name = ET.SubElement(child, 'data')
```

And they return errors or None.

Code for writing/naming XML file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element('root')
child = ET.SubElement(root, 'child')
ET.SubElement(child, 'data').text = 0000 #used for naming
ET.SubElement(child, 'more').text = 1111

name = ET.SubElement(child, 'data').text
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write(f"file_{name}.xml")
```

Example XML file:

```
<root>
  <child>
     <data>0000</data>
     <more>1111</more>
  </child>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this may be what you are looking for:

```
for i in tree.iter('data'):
    name = i.text

print(f"file_{name}.xml")
```

Output:

> file_0000.xml

Comment: yes this is, however when I add this to my code I get an error: "NameError: name 'name' is not defined". It does not seem to be entering the for loop. Any ideas why?

Comment: @AlyssaHuque - just tried `tree.write(f"file_{name}.xml")` and it wrote fine.

Comment: apologies, I realized I was typing names instead of name which is where the error was coming from. This works great, thank you so much for your help!